# RangeError: Property storage exceeds 196607 properties While fetching file buffer from server

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-query

I am creating an app for file storage
  
When a user uploads the file it is stored in the MongoDB in buffer format  
When a user requests the file the same buffer is sent into the response to the user from the server.
When that response is received, react native throws an error of
`RangeError: Property storage exceeds 196607 properties`
which ultimately crashes the app or hangs it

Here is my downloadFile code

```
import { Helpers } from '#/utils';
import { get } from 'lodash';

const downloadFile = async (fileDetails, isConnected, downloadFileMutation) => {
  const channelId =
    await Helpers.createChannelForProgressNotificationOfUploadingAndDownloadingFiles();
  const notificationId =
    await Helpers.uploadAndDownloadFileProgressNotification(
      'downloadFile',
      0,
      channelId,
      Constants.NOTIFICATION_STATUS.START,
      `Downloading ${fileDetails.name} File`
    );
  downloadFileMutation.mutate(
    {
      files: [fileDetails._id],
    },
    {
      onSuccess: async (filesDetails) => {
        console.log('filesDetails', filesDetails);
        await Helpers.cancelNotification(notificationId);
        Helpers.uploadAndDownloadFileProgressNotification(
          'downloadFile',
          1,
          channelId,
          Constants.NOTIFICATION_STATUS.END,
          `${fileDetails.name} downloaded successfully`,
          'click to view file'
        );
        const listOfFileNamesWithBuffer = filesDetails.fileBuffers.map(
          (data) => ({
            name: data.file.originalname,
            buffer: data.file.buffer.data,
          })
        );
        await Helpers.downloadAndStoreFile(listOfFileNamesWithBuffer);
      },
      onError: ({
        response: {
          data: { error },
        },
      }) => {
        Helpers.toastMessage(
          get(error, 'description', Constants.COMMON_ERROR_MESSAGE),
          'error'
        );
      },
    }
  );
};

export default downloadFile;
```

And below is my downloadFileMutation

```
import { encryptedLockerAxiosClient } from '#/utils';
import { getFilesApiEndpoint } from '#/config/routes';

const getFile = (fileIds, authToken) =>
  encryptedLockerAxiosClient
    .post(
      getFilesApiEndpoint,
      {
        ...fileIds,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: authToken,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((data) => ({
      fileBuffers: data.data,
      status: data.status,
    }));

const useGetFile = (authToken, progressCallback, options = {}) => {
  const mutation = useMutation((fileIds) => getFile(fileIds, authToken), {
    ...options,
  });

  return mutation;
};
export default useGetFile;
```